# How to change captains-log level

Tags: logging

I would like to know how to change the level of captains-log. I have a very simple project and there is no doc on https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.setLevels(
  {
    crit: 1,
    error: 2,
    warn: 3,
    info: 4,
    debug: 5,
    verbose: 6
  });

var customLogger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
  });

var log = require('captains-log')({ custom: customLogger });
```